# How to get the serilog log path from application configuration file?

Tags: c#, serilog

I have following configuration in my `appsettings.json`

```
"ApplicationLog": {
"Serilog": {
  "MinimumLevel": "Information",
  "WriteTo": [
    {
      "Name": "File",
      "Args": {
        "path": "%PROGRAMDATA%\\Logs\\AppLog-.txt",
        "fileSizeLimitBytes": 10485760,
        "retainedFileCountLimit": 10,
        "rollOnFileSizeLimit": true,
        "rollingInterval": "Day",
        "outputTemplate": "== {Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [{Number}] [{LogType}] [{ErrorCode}] [{Level}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}"
      }
    }
  ]
 }
}
```

I would like to get the `Path` from these settings. For example, the path is

> "%PROGRAMDATA%\Logs\AppLog-.txt",

I am trying it using below c# code

```
private string GetConfigurationPath()
{
    string pointer = "ApplicationLog:Serilog:WriteTo";
    string path = this._configuration.GetSection(pointer).Get<Dictionary<string, string>>().GetSection("Args:Path");
}
```

But, Unable to get it.

Also tried,

```
  string  a =  this._configuration.GetSection("ApplicationLog").GetSection("Serilog")["WriteTo"].ToString();
```

It throws a null exception!

In a quick view, I can see like below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i don't know the right syntax, but it should be something like this:

```
configuration
   .GetSection("ApplicationLog")
   .GetSection("Serilog")
   ["WriteTo"]
   .First()
   .GetSection("Args")
   ["path"]
```

Look at the json! 
This is wrong: `Serilog:WriteTo"` because `WriteTo` is not a section (or json object) its an array!

Comment: .First() - is not part of string!, updated screenshot

Comment: .First() is a linq extension method, that gets the first element of an array/list. Try it, create a list<T>() and do something like `var x = myList.First();`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to read the value as follow

```
string path  = this.GetConfigurationNestedValue("ApplicationLog:Serilog:WriteTo:0:Args:path");


private string GetConfigurationNestedValue(string pointer)
{
    return this._configuration.GetSection(pointer).Value;
}
```